# Shippo - Python Package Async Issue

Tags: shippo

I have imported the Shippo python package and I am trying to get their sample to work but I am running into the following error message (see below).  I am running Python 3.7.2 on the most current API version.

Here is the error -

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:/Users/tom/Documents/PyProjects/goShippo/goShippoCreateLabels.py", line 1, in <module>
        import shippo
      File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\shippo\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
        from shippo.resource import (
      File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\shippo\resource.py", line 303
        def get_rates(cls, object_id, async=False, api_key=None, currency=None, **params):
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is the code -

```
import shippo

shippo.api_key = "shippo_test_123456789"

address_from = {
    "name": "Shawn Ippotle",
    "company": "Shippo",
    "street1": "215 Clayton St.",
    "city": "San Francisco",
    "state": "CA",
    "zip": "94117",
    "country": "US",
    "phone": "+1 555 341 9393",
    "email": "shippotle@goshippo.com"
}

address_to = {
    "name": "Mr Hippo",
    "company": "",
    "street1": "Broadway 1",
    "street2": "",
    "city": "New York",
    "state": "NY",
    "zip": "10007",
    "country": "US",
    "phone": "+1 555 341 9393",
    "email": "mrhippo@goshippo.com",
    "metadata": "Hippos dont lie"
}

parcel = {
    "length": "5",
    "width": "5",
    "height": "5",
    "distance_unit": "in",
    "weight": "2",
    "mass_unit": "lb"
}

shipment = {
    "address_from": address_from,
    "address_to": address_to,
    "parcels": [parcel]
}

transaction = shippo.Transaction.create(
    shipment = shipment,
    carrier_account = "b741b99f95e841639b54272834bc478c",
    servicelevel_token = "usps_priority"
)
```

Answer (score 3):

This package has Python version coverage up to 3.3. In versions 3.6+, "async" became a reserved keyword causing the syntax error you're getting.

Since "async" is a default parameter, the best workaround would be to explicitly change the "async" parameter to "asynchronous". This should at least avoid the syntax error until the package is updated for 3.6+ support.